# Integrating legacy C code in multi-threaded C++ code

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, legacy

Assume we have a legacy C file with some functions to solve linear equations and several corresponding global variables.

lineq.c:

```
/* macro definitions */
...
/* global vars */
...
/* some functions that make use of above variables */
void solveLinEq(...);
```

Now we want to use this legacy library in a modern multi-threaded C++ application. Therefore, we want to write a kind of wrapper class `LinEqSolver` that provides an OO interface for solving linear equations and internally calls the functions of our legacy C library.

However, it should be possible that there are multiple instances of `LinEqSolver` used by different threads. This requires that each instance/each thread has its own copies of the global variables in `lineq.c`. How can this be achieved, if we don't want to modify the `lineq.c`?

A possible solution I can imagine is to copy the global variables and the functions from the C file into the class `LinEqSolver`, making them data and function members. Then, each instance of `LinEqSolver` would operate on its private copy of the former globale variables. However, this copy-paste programming style is rather bad, especially when there is an update to `lineq.c` and we need to copy-paste the changes into our code again.

What other possibilities do I have where the actual code to solve linear equations stays in `lineq.c` and is just called from `LinEqSolver`?

Comment: Just a friendly comment: C is not more legacy than C++ is in some fields. In its field of application it is as modern as C++. Surprisingly, you can also easily write C multithreaded programs. Even more interesting: most of the threading features of the core langauge are very similar.

Comment: Sorry, but if you have global variables and don't want to touch the original code, then there is basically nothing you can do.

Comment: @Olaf: It sounds like the lineq library is legacy code, due to how / when it was written - not because it uses C.

Comment: Is thete a realistic chance, you will ever get updates for lineq? The program structure sounds like something that hasn't been touched for a while.

Comment: @MikeMB: I mostly refer to the antipodes "legacy" and "modern", not about a "legacy library" as such. On purpose or not, imho OP invokes a wrong impression. I might be a bit thin-skinned about that subject, but I have my reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `thread_local` keyword from C++11. This will work well if your function **always** initializes all needed static variables in the beginning.

If you have more complex picture - more work will be needed. For example:

```
int myVar1, myVar2;

void InitStaticVars()
{
   ....
}

void solveLinEq(...);
```

If you will simply add `thread_local` specifier to the variables above and call initialization function at the beginning of your program, it will initialize these variables only for the calling thread. On all other threads their initial values will be zeroes.

Comment: I've just read some stuff about thread_local and it sounds promising. However, as far as I understand it, it should work if I simply add the thread_local specifier, without further limitations. Could you explain your constraint a bit further?

Answer (score 1):

You could put `lineq.c` in a shared object and load it multiple times with `dlopen` and `RTLD_PRIVATE` and use `dlsym` for each thread, so the global variables are separate for every thread. Unfortunately `RTLD_PRIVATE` isn't supported by glibc. Workaround for this would be to copy the shared object for every thread with a distinct name and use `dlopen` to the copy of the shared object with `RTLD_LOCAL`. `lineq.c` remains untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I would just bite the bullet and modify it to add the globals into a struct that should be passed as a pointer to all calls in lineq.c.

It is then easy to wrap this with a c++ class and have an instance per thread etc.

Another alternative would be to modify the c file to use __declspec(thread) or similar.  However if you plan to put this code in a dll then you can expect insurmountable problems with that (on Windows, at least).